# Can I add html attribute to html data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have trouble with bind a tooltip attribute to a value from my jquery plugin.I have an idea and I just want to implement it,since I need to know how to bind a html element to a value.In my plugin i pass the value using `this.data("number",number)`.Is it possible to pass with some extra attibute to the number like `addClass('tooltip')` and call the function to the class like `$('.class').tooltipser()`.

Is it possible for me to do this in jquery

**Note that number is a vaule that I passing to a variable**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with `attr()`

```
$('.class').attr('yourAttribute', yourValue);
```

Notice that you can create custom attributes.

Then you can fetch the element with the attribute this way -

`$('.class[yourAttribute]')`